# Case Insensitive Pattern Matching over String Lists

Tags: string, f#, pattern-matching, match, case-insensitive

I'm trying to parse command line arguments in an F# application. I'm using pattern matching over parameters list to accomplish it. Something like:

```
let rec parseCmdLnArgs = 
  function
  | [] -> { OutputFile = None ; OtherParam = None }
  | "/out" :: fileName :: rest -> let parsedRest = parseCmdLnArgs rest
                                  { OutputFile = Some(fileName) with parsedRest }
```

The problem is I want to make `"/out"` match case insensitive while preserving the case of other stuff. That means I can't alter the input and match the lowercase version of the input against it (this will lose the `fileName` case information).

I have thought about several solutions:

- Resort to `when` clauses which is less than ideal.
- Match a tuple each time, the first would be the actual parameter (which I'll just save for further processing and will wildcard match it) and the second would be the lowercased version used in such matchings. This looks worse than the first.
- Use active patterns but that looks too verbose. I'll have to repeat things like `ToLower "/out"` before every item.

Is there a better option/pattern for doing these kind of stuff? I think this is a common problem and there should be a good way to handle it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I quite like your idea of using F# active patterns to solve this. It is a bit more verbose than using pre-processing, but I think it's quite elegant. Also, according to [some BCL guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/06/01/424012.aspx), you shouldn't be using `ToLower` when comparing strings (ignoring the case). The right approach is to use `OrdinalIgnoreCase` flag. You can still define a nice active pattern to do this for you:

```
open System

let (|InvariantEqual|_|) (str:string) arg = 
  if String.Compare(str, arg, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0
    then Some() else None

match "HellO" with
| InvariantEqual "hello" -> printfn "yep!"
| _ -> printfn "Nop!"
```

You're right that it's more verbose, but it nicely hides the logic and it gives you enough power to use the recommended coding style (I'm not sure how this could be done using pre-processing).

Comment: I find the name `InvariantEqual` to be misleading since you are using `OrdinalIgnoreCase` not `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 2):

I might do some pre-processing to allow for either "-" or "/" at the beginning of keywords, and to normalize the case:

```
let normalize (arg:string) =
    if arg.[0] = '/' || arg.[0] = '-' then 
        ("-" + arg.[1..].ToLower())
    else arg
let normalized = args |> List.map normalize
```

It's perhaps not ideal, but it's not like any user is going to have enough patience to type so many command-line parameters that looping through them twice is noticeably slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use guards to match your deal:

```
let rec parseCmdLnArgs = 
  function
  | [] -> { OutputFile = None ; OtherParam = None }
  | root :: fileName :: rest when root.ToUpper() = "/OUT" -> let parsedRest = parseCmdLnArgs rest
                                  { OutputFile = Some(fileName) with parsedRest }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this looking for a solution to a similar issue, and while Tomas' solution works for individual strings, it doesn't help with the original issue of pattern matching against lists of strings. A modified version of his active pattern allows matching lists:

```
let (|InvariantEqual|_|) : string list -> string list -> unit option =
    fun x y ->
        let f : unit option -> string * string -> unit option =
            fun state (x, y) ->
                match state with
                | None -> None
                | Some() ->
                    if x.Equals(y, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    then Some()
                    else None
        if x.Length <> y.Length then None
        else List.zip x y |> List.fold f (Some())

match ["HeLlO wOrLd"] with
| InvariantEqual ["hello World";"Part Two!"] -> printfn "Bad input"
| InvariantEqual ["hello WORLD"] -> printfn "World says hello"
| _ -> printfn "No match found"
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to make it match with placeholders properly to do `| InvariantEqual "/out" :: fileName :: rest -> ...` yet, but if you know the entire contents of the list, it's an improvement.